# ODBC Comman add multiple parameters with one value

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, odbc

I have a postgresql query that has multiple parameters, I understand how that parameters using OdbcCommand in C# are position based and not name based, however all of the parameters will have the same value, I am wondering if there is a way to only assign the parameter value once instead of four times.

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@clientid", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = clientid;
```

instead of

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@clientid", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = clientid;
comm.Parameters.Add("@clientid", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = clientid;
comm.Parameters.Add("@clientid", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = clientid;
comm.Parameters.Add("@clientid", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = clientid;
```

Below is the query I will be using

```
    SELECT cp.blkofbusid            AS LOB,
       cp.clientid              AS GroupID,
       cp.locationname          AS Division, 
       benefitplanid, 
      ( select clientname from client where clientid=? and blkofbusid <> 'HOLD')
FROM   clientpricovebenefitplan cp
       LEFT OUTER JOIN clientlocation cl
                ON cp.clientid = cl.clientid
                AND cp.locationname = CASE WHEN cp.locationname <> 'N/A' THEN cl.locationname ELSE cp.locationname END
WHERE  cp.clientid =?
       AND cp.locationname IN 
       (
                SELECT CASE
                        WHEN cpb.locationname <> 'N/A' AND (SELECT Count(a.locationname) FROM clientpricovebenefitplan a WHERE  a.locationname <> 'N/A' AND a.clientid =? and blkofbusid <> 'HOLD') > 0 THEN
                                locationname
                        WHEN (SELECT Count(b.locationname) FROM clientpricovebenefitplan b WHERE  b.locationname <> 'N/A' AND b.clientid =? and blkofbusid <> 'HOLD') = 0 THEN
                                'N/A'
                        END AS divcode
                FROM clientpricovebenefitplan cpb
                WHERE  
                        cpb.clientid =?
        )
ORDER BY
        division
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible if using ODBC. In ODBC, named parameters are used only in calls to stored procedures and cannot be used in other SQL statements. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/binding-parameters-by-name-named-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15.

However, it is possible if using .Net Oracle driver, not ODBC.

Comment: The oracle driver is exactly what I was looking for, thanks